# Arbitrary length keys to standard key length in AES

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I was asked to implement the AES algorithm for a security class. While implementing i couldn't find answer on how i can accept a key like a password, with arbitrary length, from the user and convert it to 128, 192 or 256-bit key. What should i do?

Comment: You can derive a key from a password with a key derivation function (KDF) like PBKDF2, see e.g. https://cryptobook.nakov.com/mac-and-key-derivation/kdf-deriving-key-from-password. You can find a lot of information about this on the web.

Comment: If you are going to use a KDF, which you should, then it is better to use a passphrase as it is longer than a single password.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, this is typically done with a key derivation function (KDF).  There are two main types of key derivation functions that are used.

The first kind is used when you have some type of cryptographic material already, oftentimes some variant of a key exchange (usually, Diffie-Hellman).  In this case, the key material is assumed to be strong and you just want to distill it and generate potentially multiple keys from it.  [HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869), which is used in TLS 1.3, and the TLS 1.2 PRF are good examples of this.  They are generally wrappers around HMAC, and they're pretty fast.

The second kind is used when you have a password.  Because, in general, people are bad at coming up with and remembering passwords with sufficient entropy, we use a KDF that is specifically iterated so as to be slow, such as the older PBKDF2 or the newer [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) and [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2).  These options are designed to use a unique salt and be iterated many times so that users who pick poor passwords are afforded at least some level of protection against compromise, and the newer options are designed to be expensive in memory to prevent efficient attacks on GPUs.